# add_image_size wordpress crop array (top, bottom) not working

Tags: css, wordpress, image, crop

I have some problem. I want upload image but its crop to center. I want to top left...

I inserted this code:

```
add_image_size( 'photo-thumb', $gllr_options['gllr_custom_size_px'][1][0], $gllr_options['gllr_custom_size_px'][1][1],array('center', 'top') );
```

But previously was:

```
add_image_size( 'photo-thumb', $gllr_options['gllr_custom_size_px'][1][0], $gllr_options['gllr_custom_size_px'][1][1], True );
```

If I delete true, then script don't crop. I think code is function but when i write `array('center', 'top')` then still cropping to `center center`.

Answer (score 0):

The last argument of add_image_size accept array of crop area. The first key is X axis and second key is Y axis. So you need to pass left and top.

```
add_image_size( 'photo-thumb', $width, $height, array('left', 'top') );
```

Comment: Thanks. But not working. Still **center, center**. Also if i have **top, center** then its **center center**.

Comment: Already cropped image will not be crop again. You must regenerate thumbnails using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Answer (score 0):

**Crop Mode**

**Set the image size by resizing the image proportionally (without distorting it):**

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 180 ); // 220 pixels wide by 180 pixels tall, soft proportional crop mode
```

**Set the image size by cropping the image (not showing part of it):**

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 220, array( 'left', 'top' ) ); // Hard crop left top
```

**Set the image size by cropping the image and defining a crop position:**

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 220, array( 'left', 'top' ) ); // Hard crop left top
```

**NOTE:** When setting a crop position, the first value in the array is the x axis crop position, the second is the y axis crop position.

x_crop_position accepts ‘left’ ‘center’, or ‘right’.

y_crop_position accepts ‘top’, ‘center’, or ‘bottom’.

If this functions not work may be you have problem with codes in functions.php

**Other Notes:**

Using the ‘false’ setting will fail to produce a new image in the upload directory if one of the image dimensions of the uploaded image are equal to the new image size.

If a registered image size is removed from functions.php, then any image uploaded before that point and then deleted from the media library afterwards, does not have those auto-generated sizes deleted too. Only image sizes that exist in functions.php are deleted.

Although height and width are not required parameters, their default values (0) will lead to unwanted behavior, so bear in mind that you should always define them. As mentioned before, use a value of 9999 to define the other dimension as the one to be considered when image resize is executed.